# Why is the current through the resistor E 0?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]

What principles do i need to know to solve these sorts of problems?

Comment: Just the principle of wheatstone bridge

Answer (score 1):

It is a special case of a balanced Wheatstone bridge. Regard both branches as voltage dividers, and you will see that there is a 2:3 ratio in both of them. There is then no voltage difference between the terminals of resistance E.

In general, one needs to apply Kirchhoff's laws for such circuits.